# Shell-Script: How can I pull a random letter sequence from a file?

Tags: shell, grep, passwords

I'm writing a script which is supposed to automatically change test users passwords.
I have a dictionary file which includes all the relevant passwords I'm bound to use and I'm trying to understand how to pull some random passwords from the file in order to set the new passwords and document which test user got which password... I'm having a hard time to find the right pattern I should use, can you please assist?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there a special reason for using grep? I can imagine doing something like this using bash and the cat command.

Comment: Any way is welcomed... I thought it's done with grep...

Comment: I've edited my answer with a couple of hints for you. I have to get a move on now, but I'll see if I can get back to you later this evening. If you have specific questions about bash, I'm sure there are lots of people out there with answers. Happy scripting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your shell supports `$RANDOM` (bash does) and the allowed passwords are contained, one password per line, in a file whose name is `paswd` you can try

```
new_pass=$(awk NR==$RANDOM'%'`wc -l paswd| cut -d\  -f1`'+1' paswd)
```

---

#### Example using a different file

```
for x in {1..5} ; do 
> a=$(mawk NR==$RANDOM'%'`wc -l .bashrc| cut -d\  -f1`'+1' .bashrc)
> echo $x "$a"
> done
1     muvi ${1}"$num" && break
2    $1/* ; }
3 alias acse='apt-cache search'
4 xc () { export cnt=`expr $cnt + 1` ; u=$1; shift ; x $lett`printf "%4.4d" $cnt` $u -1 $* ; }
5 alias logout='xfce4-session-logout --logout'
%
```

Comment: @Itai I wonder if you'd like to change the title of your question to something alike "shell script: choosing a random line from a file", as it seems to me that it would be more meaningful for more people... tx for approval.

Answer (score 0):

The following approach will work for a modestly sized password dictionary.

- read the passwords into a bash array
- start a while loop
- prompt for the user's login-id
- read the id
- use $RANDOM to generate an index into the array
- pull out the password at that position (you'll have to use some mod arithmetic)
- use `passwd` command to change the password (check the man page)
- log the user and either the number or the passwd as you desire
- back to the start of the loop

You can exit the loop based on something like an empty name being entered.

I hope that's of some help.

06.11.2014
I've editted this answer with a complete, if somewhat unspectacular solution. This is for anyone who, like me, has difficulty understanding the brevity of the preferred solution. Points to note:

- In bash you have to declare an array with `declare -a YourArray`
- You should also specify a dedicated index variable: `arrIdx=0` for instance
- Bash arrays are dynamic so you don't need to declare its size.

Here's the whole thing:

```
#!/bin/bash
PRG=`basename $0`
if [ $# -lt 2 ]; then
  echo "usage $PRG password_file change_log"
  exit -1
fi
INFILE=$1
LOGFILE=$2
declare -a passwdArr
arrIdx=0
newPasswd= 

for inputPasswd in `cat $INFILE`; do
    passwdArr[$arrIdx]=$inputPasswd
    echo "inputPasswd = $inputPasswd, arrIdx = $arrIdx, passwdArr[arrIdx] = ${passwdArr[$arrIdx]}"
    ((arrIdx += 1)) # double parentheses ensure arithmetic evaluation
done

arrSize=$arrIdx # one more than the mximum index

USER="xxx"
while [ "$USER" != "" ]; do
    echo "enter user ID:"
    read USER
    if [ "$USER" != "" ]; then # Do nothing in this case
        arrIdx=`expr $RANDOM % $arrSize`
        echo "arrIdx = $arrIdx"
        newPasswd=${passwdArr[$arrIdx]}
        echo "$arrIdx $USER $newPasswd" >> $LOGFILE
        echo -e "$newPasswd\n$newPasswd" | passwd  $USER
    fi
done
```

**Important...** the test `if [ "$USER" != "" ]` within the loop is required in order to avoid inadvertently changing the password of the administrator running the script!

Comment: It's a nice detailed answer but I have no idea how to execute it